# want to take a value of a key from a list of objects in Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, object, dart

**I have a list as below and i want to get the value of label of the first object in the list in flutter.**

i used `var label=result[0];`
so i got the first object as output. but from here how can i take the label value.

```
result = [
    {
        confidence: 0.6177453994750977, 
        index: 403547, 
        label: 403547|nittardi ad astra maremma toscana 2006
    }, 
    {
        confidence: 0.5917310118675232, 
        index: 297224, 
        label: 297224|agostina pieri brunello di montalcino 2013
    }, 
    {
        confidence: 0.5917310118675232, 
        index: 297225, 
        label: 297225|agostina pieri brunello di montalcino 2010
    }, 
    {
        confidence: 0.5917307734489441, 
        index: 297223,
        label: 297223|agostina pieri brunello di montalcino
    }
]
```

Comment: label=result[0][‘label']; :)

Comment: @Fatimaayaa You can put it as an answer below before others copy yours and write